# How to replace a element based on value in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Is there an equivalent function to `replace` a value in a vector just like `erase`.

The following line of code currently removes any value that is present in `BC`.

```
vector<double> activeDof;    
for (int i = 0; i < BC.size(); i++)
{
    activeDof.erase(find(activeDof.begin(), activeDof.end(), BC[i]));
}
```

This reduces my size of vector and messes up my code later on. What I would like to do is to is replace the values in BC with zero. So that I will still have the same number of elements in my vector. I tried to use the replace function as shown below.

```
vector<double> activeDof; 
for (int i = 0; i < BC.size(); i++)
{
    replace(activeDof.begin(),activeDof.end(),BC[i],0);
}
```

I still get an error message underneath "replace". Any recommendations on how to replace a element based on value in a vector?

**Edit**: BC is another vector which contains some elements. I want to find out if this element is present in the vector activeDof and if it is present I want to turn that to 0.

Comment: What is `BC` in your code?

Comment: I think you are confusing `BC` with `activeDof`? You are performing replace on the elements of vector `activeDof` but you expect changes in `BC`? "_What I would like to do is to is replace the values in BC with zero_"?

Comment: BC is another vector containing some elements

Comment: What are the types of those elements in `BC`?

Comment: Both are vectors of type double

Comment: `0` is an `int`, not a `double`. Simply change it to `0.0`.

Comment: Please be aware of floating-point comparison. The error message instead of *"red wiggly line"* statement is more appreciated next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change '0' to '0.0' in

```
replace(activeDof.begin(),activeDof.end(),BC[i],0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   vector<double> activeDof {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};
   vector<double> BC {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0};

   for (auto d: BC)
      replace (activeDof.begin(), activeDof.end(), d, 0.0);

   for (auto a: activeDof)
      cout << a << "-";

   return 0;
}
```

produce this output:

```
0-0-0-0-0-0-7-8-
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem is you are not able to erase element correctly as you are not  doing erase properly

Replace is good strategy but not required if you can erase the element properly

You can fix your code as mentioned below

```
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
vector<double> activeDof;
for (int i = 0; i < BC.size(); i++)

{
    activeDof.erase(std::remove(activeDof.begin(), activeDof.end(), BC[i])), activeDof.end());
    activeDof.shrink_to_fit();

}
```